# getStreamVolume giving null pointer exception

Tags: android, audio

I have used the same command in 5 different applications without problem (as part of my SoundManager):

```
float streamVolume = mAudioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

but now it's giving me a null point exception based on my log commands. Why??????

The only things that have changed are the sounds. I have used log commands to see what sound it is trying to play and checked if the sounds are in the sound manager and they are but does that even matter as all this command does is try to get the phones set play volume?

Comment: If you're getting a NPE from this line of code, then mAudioManager has to be null. We can't help you any more than that without seeing how you define & initialize mAudioManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Wesley, That was it. I added:

```
SoundManager.initSounds(getApplicationContext());
SoundManager.loadSounds();
```

and it's working fine now.